# Setting up Selenium with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, selenium

Really basic question here but for some reason I can't find a VB.NET tutorial. I've used selenium on a load of other projects in ruby so this is really bugging me!

I've downloaded selenium-dot-net from google code, i've also downloaded the IEDriver.exe how do I instantiate the driver in vb code?

Thanks

Marc

Edit

To be clear i've imported webdriver.support.dll and webdriver.dll and the code so far looks like(this throws an error saying the service isnt running which is fair enough since I haven't started iedriver.exe)

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.IE
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI

Public Class SearchForm
    Private Sub SearchForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim mydriver as new InternetExplorerDriver

    End Sub
```

Comment: Right i've sorted it will update in a couple of hours with tested working solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok simple way to do this:

You need to download the driver for the browser you want to work with from the selenium website. Download, extract and keep a note of the path you extracted it to.

Then in your code:

```
Dim mydriver As New ChromeDriver("C:\Users\Marc\Downloads\chromedriver_win32")
```

Thats it, you now have access to all the Selenium you need!