# How to webscrape using Visual Basic for Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get into web scraping. I'm familiar with VB and C#. I decided to go with VB.
When I write my code in an Excel module, it is able to import the Selenium library.
I prefer to write some code in Visual Studio. When I try to import the OpenQA.Selenium libraries in Visual Studio. I keep getting an error:

warning BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'OpenQA.Selenium' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

warning BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

I don't understand. I've installed all the necessary Selenium packages. I've downloaded the latest chromedriver. I add references to my .dll files. What could be the issue?

Comment: Checked for any other questions on here that ask about webscraping and even have example code?

Comment: Visual Studio is not necessary for Excel VBA. Try [this](https://davetallett26.github.io/SOExcelHW.html) to get started with Excel VBA

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216623/using-google-chrome-in-selenium-vba-installation-steps/77343812#77343812) answer should help with Excel VBA Selenium Chrome

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091482/setting-up-selenium-with-vb-net) should help with setting up selenium with VB.NET